# NSArray sort arrays

Tags: objective-c, arrays, sorting

There are several `NSArray` objects in a `NSArray`.

Example code is like this

```
NSArray *a1 = @[@3, @3, @2];
NSArray *a2 = @[@2, @4, @5];
NSArray *a3 = @[@2, @5, @1];
NSArray *array = @[a1, a2, a3];
```

How do I sort `a1`, `a2` and `a3` in numerical/alphabetical/logical order?

Comment: What's "a dictionary order"?

Comment: might be new order introduce by some one that we are not recognize :) @trojanfoe

Comment: In that case, sort result should be a2, a3, a1. For example, banana comes after apple, and apple comes before application. Do you know what I mean? @trojanfoe

Comment: But "banana" and "apple" and "application" don't appear in that code.  If you are trying to say "alphabetical order" then that doesn't mean much as there are no strings in the code either.

Comment: Ah that was just an example of "dictionary order"

Comment: OK so you mean "alphabetical order", but that only makes sense with strings.

Comment: You want to sort the array according to the variable name of the array ?

Comment: No, the value of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that each array contains only instances of `NSNumber` this should work:

```
NSArray *sorted = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSArray *array1, NSArray *array2) {

    NSString *str1 = [array1 componentsJoinedByString:@"|"];
    NSString *str2 = [array2 componentsJoinedByString:@"|"];

    return [str1 compare:str2];

}];
```

I doubt it'll be particularly efficient with larger data sets though.